# "Missing required parameters for [Route: property.edit]" error when editing product

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, routes, relation

I am trying to edit a product, but my route is not working. Please let me know how to get this resource route working.

This is my web file:

```
Route::resource('product', 'ProductController')->except([
    'store', 'update', 'destroy', 'edit'
]);
```

Here is my controller file:

```
public function edit($product)
{
  $product=Product::find($product);
  return view('admin.product.edit', compact($product));
}
```

Here is my view file:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('property.edit') }}">Edit</a></li>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you try to edit a resource you should provide the id to the resource. So if you run `php artisan route:list` you will see that your `product` route for editing expects an argument, something like this:
`'product/{product}/edit'`, in order to make it work, you should do the following:

```
<li><a href="{{ route('property.edit', $property) }}">Edit</a></li>
```

or

```
<li><a href="{{ route('property.edit', $property->id) }}">Edit</a></li>
```

Third option

```
<li>
<a href="{{ route('property.edit', ['id' => $property->id]) }}">Edit</a>
</li>
```

Your named route is called `property.edit` and you shared the `product` route with us, so please edit your question and provide the details. But in any case you are missing the argument hence the error.

Comment: I am getting the HTML Code in URL when I am editing.

Comment: I just noticed you are not even generating a route for the `edit` url, so can you share your named route `property.edit`. Because you shared `product` route which has nothing to do with this.

Comment: This is my Property Route:
Route::resource('property', 'PropertyController')->except([
  'store', 'update', 'destroy', 'edit'
 ]);

Comment: @sumit I edited my answer with a third option. You are not sharing the right details, so I cannot help with what you need exactly, but the error that you get is because you are not passing an argument to the route for sure.

Comment: You know that when you say `except` that means **do not** generate named routes for this functions? You should use `only` instead, or I don't understand your problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing parameter to your route. The Route expecting a parameter. lets say you need to edit the product but you have to know which product you want to edit for this you pass your product id or product slug with the help you fetch the record right.

There are you doing mistake. you passing nothing. just do something below

```
<li><a href="{{ route('property.edit', $product->id) }}">Edit</a></li>
```

In the above code passing id as a parameter and in controller getting result by passing received id from route like below.

```
$product=Product::find($product);
return view('admin.product.edit', compact($product));
```

If you want to see you route list and methods and arguments of every route required
you can run this command in terminal `php artisan route:list`