# 404 Page with Laravel 10, Inertia JS and Vuejs using resource routing

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I just started a new project with Laravel 10, InertiaJS and Vue3.

I set up two simple models, `Blog` and `Listings`. Since this is my first project with Inertia and Vue, I created the blog from a tutorial(for the frame of reference).  All CRUD resource routes for `blog` work as they should.  So I generated all `listings` resources to mirror `blog`.  The only routes that work for `listings` are index, create and store--I get a 404 error on the edit and destroy routes. I am out of ideas.

**debug-bar error when trying to edit or delete a listing**

```
...
No query results for model [App\Models\Listing] 1
...
```

**web.php**

```
...
Route::resource('stories',StoryController::class); (my blog routes)
Route::resource('listings',ListingController::class);
...
```

**ListingsController.php**

```
...
public function edit(Listing $listing)
{

    return Inertia::render(
        'Listings/Edit',
        [
            'listing' => $listing
        ]
    );
}
...
public function destroy(Listing $listing)
{
    $listing->delete();
    sleep(1);

    return redirect()->route('listings.index')->with('message', 'Listing Delete Successfully');
}
```

**Listings/Index.vue**

```
<script setup>
import AuthenticatedLayout from "@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue";
import PrimaryButton from "@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue";
import { Head, Link, useForm } from "@inertiajs/vue3";

const props = defineProps({
    listings: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({}),
    },
});
const form = useForm({});

function destroy(id) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete")) {
        form.delete(route("listings.destroy", id));
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <Head title="Listings" />

    <AuthenticatedLayout>
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="text-xl font-semibold leading-tight text-gray-800">
                Listings Index
            </h2>
        </template>

        <div class="py-12">
            <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <div class="overflow-hidden bg-white shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                    <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                        <div class="mb-2">
                            <Link :href="route('listings.create')">
                                <PrimaryButton>Add Listing</PrimaryButton>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relative overflow-x-auto shadow-md sm:rounded-lg">
                            <table class="w-full text-sm text-left text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">
                                <thead
                                    class="text-xs text-gray-700 uppercase bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">#</th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                                        Author
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                                        Title
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                                        Edit
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3">
                                        Delete
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr v-for="listing in listings" :key="listing.id"
                                    class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                                    <th scope="row"
                                        class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white whitespace-nowrap">
                                        {{ listing.id }}
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="row"
                                        class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white whitespace-nowrap">
                                        {{ listing.user.first_name }} {{ listing.user.last_name }}
                                    </th>
                                    <th scope="row"
                                        class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white whitespace-nowrap">
                                        {{ listing.title }}
                                    </th>
                                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                        <Link :href="route('listings.edit', listing.id)
                                                " class="px-4 py-2 text-white bg-blue-600 rounded-lg">Edit</Link>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="px-6 py-4">
                                        <PrimaryButton class="bg-red-700" @click="destroy(listing.id)">
                                            Delete
                                        </PrimaryButton>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </AuthenticatedLayout>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem, but you're using named routes for the edit and delete and the resource in the routes.php does not have a name() method.

Try adding the name method to the route.  Or, alternatively, you could try specifying the full route (without using the route() function) in your links.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56250383/missing-required-parameters-for-route-property-edit-error-when-editing-prod)

**Changed**

```
:href="route('listings.edit', listing.id)
```

**To**

```
:href="route('listings.edit', listing)
```

Not sure why my `blog` resources worked fine without these changes.

Comment: That's strange because your initial version looks correct.  Well, as long as it now works! :)